# TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm having this problem and I have no ideea why is not working.
I'm pretty new to python so I will appreciate if you can help me

It's a very simple GUI, first page open another page when clicking on a button and on a second page I need to open a browse window and take the path as string

Thats the **Main Page**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from testGui import Ui_Test

class Ui_PragrammingGUI(object):
    def open_test_window(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Test()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.ui.get_all_serials()
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, PragrammingGUI):
        PragrammingGUI.setObjectName("PragrammingGUI")
        PragrammingGUI.resize(237, 177)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(PragrammingGUI)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    
        self.test_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.test_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 100, 121, 31))
        self.test_2.setObjectName("test_2")
        self.test_2.clicked.connect(self.open_test_window)

        PragrammingGUI.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(PragrammingGUI)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 237, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        PragrammingGUI.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(PragrammingGUI)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        PragrammingGUI.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(PragrammingGUI)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PragrammingGUI)

    def retranslateUi(self, PragrammingGUI):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PragrammingGUI.setWindowTitle(_translate("PragrammingGUI", "Programming"))
        self.test_2.setText(_translate("PragrammingGUI", "TEST"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PragrammingGUI = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_PragrammingGUI()
    ui.setupUi(PragrammingGUI)
    PragrammingGUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the one which have browse in it is (ignore the get_all_serials method):

```
import sys
import os
from cameraID import CameraID
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Test(QDialog):

    def browse_file_src(self):
        print('in the function')
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home/qauser/')
        self.lineEdit.setText(file_name[0])

    def get_all_serials(self):
        self.serial = CameraID()
        self.serial.getAllSerial()
        return_list = self.serial.getAllSerial()
        if len(return_list) > 0:
            for i in return_list:
                self.comboBox.addItem(i)
        else:
            self.comboBox.addItem("None")

    def setupUi(self, Test):
        Test.setObjectName("Test")
        Test.resize(397, 108)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 291, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Chose file")

        self.browseBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)#, clicked=lambda: self.browseBtn)
        self.browseBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 10, 80, 23))
        self.browseBtn.setObjectName("browseBtn")
        self.browseBtn.clicked.connect(self.browseBtn)

        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 51, 21))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")

        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 71, 21))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 40, 80, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 181, 23))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")

        Test.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Test)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 397, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Test.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Test)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Test.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Test)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Test.setWindowTitle(_translate("Test", "MainWindow"))
        self.browseBtn.setText(_translate("Test", "Browse"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Test", "Ok"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Test", "Failed"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Test", "Start"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Test = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Test()
    ui.setupUi(Test)
    Test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Besides the issue noted by Matt (which in my opinion is a typo, and, as such, offtopic on StackOverflow) you're also editing pyuic generated files, which is considered a bad practice. And you're also doing it in the wrong way, considering that you changed the base class of `Ui_Test` to QDialog, which is pointless for two reasons: 1. you're *not* using that class *as* a Qt widget; 2. you're actually using a QMainWindow for it. The *only* proper way to use pyuic files is by following the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is this: `self.browseBtn.clicked.connect(self.browseBtn)`.
You are trying to connect the click event to the button itself.

You probably want to do something like: `self.browseBtn.clicked.connect(self.method_to_call_when_clicked)` where method_to_call_when_clicked is replaced by the name of the method you wish to call when it is clicked.

An example already in your code is:
`self.test_2.clicked.connect(self.open_test_window)`

Comment: Of course this is what I was trying to do, I'm just too dump and missed this even if I was looking for hours for the error. Thanks a lot bro!